# Why do Steen and Seebach say an ultrafilter can only have at most one cluster point?

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory, filters

There's probably a really obvious answer that I've overlooked, but please can someone tell me why an ultrafilter can have at most one cluster point (according to page 10 of the book *Counterexamples in topology* by Steen & Seebach).  Specifically, the book says:

> If a point $x$ is in all the sets of a filter we call it a **cluster point**; clearly an ultrafilter can have at most one cluster point.

They give no additional explanation of why this is "clear", and I don't see why.

Comment: Is your space Hausdorff?

Comment: @JonathanZsupportsMonicaC not necessarily, although it could be a mistaken omission from the book.

Comment: The definition of "cluster point" that Steen & Seebach are using is nonstandard (Henno Brandsma's answer is addressing the standard definition which is totally different).  By their definition, if $x$ and $y$ are two different cluster points of a filter $F$, then every element of $F$ contains both $x$ and $y$.  So, $F$ contains neither $\{x\}$ nor $X-\{x\}$ (since neither contains both $x$ and $y$), which means it cannot be an ultrafilter.

Comment: Aha OK.. I was assuming they were talking about topologies in the filter section of the book (page 9), and assumed that the members of the filter have to be open sets (which {x} might not be), but on closer inspection of the text it doesn't mention anything about topologies or open sets in that section, and so a filter may contain any subsets including {x} or X-{x}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is false unless the space is Hausdorff. Consider the indiscrete space where any point is a cluster point (and limit) of any (ultra)filter in the space.

Comment: That makes sense. Perhaps Steen & Seebach meant Hausdorf spaces, but forgot to mention it.

Comment: Actually, what's going on is that Steen & Seebach are using a nonstandard definition of "cluster point".